# Multi directory makefile for project

Tags: makefile, multiple-makefiles

**This is how my directory looks like:**

```
/project
    makefile
    /ceda_lib
        makefile
        files....
    /general
        makefile
        files....
    /CLI
        makefile
        files....
    /objects
         files.o
```

**Makefile(main):**

```
1  #start other makefiles
2  
3 
4  o= ./objects
5  DEPS= Affine.hpp CEDA.hpp generalParameters.hpp generalFunctions.hpp
6  OBJ= $o/main.o $o/Affine.o $o/generalFunctions.o
7  CC=g++
8  CFLAGS= -Wall -g -I.
9  export CC
10 export CFLAGS
11 export DEPS
12 
13 all: 
14 ▸---+$(MAKE) -C general
15 ▸---+$(MAKE) -C ceda_lib 
16 ▸---+$(MAKE) -C CLI
17 
18 run: $(OBJ) $(DEPS)
19 ▸---$(CC) -o $@ $^
```

**The other makefiles look like this:(update2)**

```
  1 include ../makefile.variables
  2 
  3 OBJ = main.o
  4 all: $(OBJ)
  5 
  6 $(OBJ): %.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
  7 ▸---$(CC) -o ../objects/$@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)
```

What I want to do is for all code in the 3 directories to be compiled and all objects to be stored in the /object directory. Then an executable will be created from the $DEPS and the contents of /object directory.

*This makefile doesn't work sadly. Could you please find what I've done wrong and also could you suggest me ways to improve the code. (I'm quite new to makefiles).*

Also this is the output whenever I try making the project:**(Update2)**

```
make: Entering directory '/home/george/Documents/CEDA'
make -C general
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/george/Documents/CEDA/general'
g++ -o ../objects/generalFunctions.o -c generalFunctions.cpp -Wall -g -I.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/george/Documents/CEDA/general'
make -C ceda_lib
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/george/Documents/CEDA/ceda_lib'
g++ -o ../objects/Affine.o -c Affine.cpp -Wall -g -I.
Affine.cpp:4:33: fatal error: generalParameters.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "generalParameters.hpp"
                                 ^
compilation terminated.
makefile:7: recipe for target 'Affine.o' failed
make[1]: *** [Affine.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/george/Documents/CEDA/ceda_lib'
makefile:8: recipe for target 'All' failed
make: *** [All] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/george/Documents/CEDA'
```

**This is the makefile.variables**

```
  1 #variables used by all makefiles in project directory
  2 
  3 PATH_TO_DIR = ~/Documents/CEDA
  4 c = $(PATH_TO_DIR)/ceda_lib
  5 g = $(PATH_TO_DIR)/general
  6 e = $(PATH_TO_DIR)/CLI         #e for executable
  7 
  8 DEPS= $c/Affine.hpp $c/CEDA.hpp $g/generalParameters.hpp $g/generalFunctions.hpp
  9 CC=g++
 10 CFLAGS= -Wall -g -I.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
OBJ= main.o

../objects/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS)
```

This makefile contains one rule, which is a pattern rule, a way to build any file with a name like `../objects/foo.o`. But it doesn't tell Make *which* object file it is to build. To be precise, a pattern rule cannot be the default rule.

The simplest way to fix this is with the addition of an ordinary rule:

```
../objects/$(OBJ):
```

Once you have this working you will have the object files, but there are still problems in the main makefile. The `run` rule will not build an executable, and if you want to execute that rule you will have to invoke it on the command line, it won't follow automatically.

You are attempting recursive use of Make -- which is tricky -- before you've mastered the basics. I suggest you try using the makefile to build the object files, then try to build the executable using the command line, then look carefully at the command you used and rewrite the `run` rule.

Once you get that far, other improvements are possible. (Make is a powerful tool, but it has a long learning curve.)

**EDIT:** If it isn't working at all, try something simpler first.

Pick a source file in `ceda_lib`, like, I don't know `main.cpp`. Verify that the source file exists and that the corresponding object file (`main.o`) does not. Edit the makefile (in `ceda_lib/`) to this:

```
main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Then within `ceda_lib/`, try `make` and see what happens.

If it builds `main.o`, then delete `main.o`, and then from `project/` try `make -C ceda_lib`, and see what happens. If that builds `ceda_lib/main.o`, then we can move on to more advanced makefiles.

Comment: I think I've not used correctly the "export". Could you help me a bit more please? I added the ../objects/$(OBJ): rule and now it all executes but it doesn't compile anything. It just goes into the makefiles in order and says: Nothing to be done for ..

Comment: @alienCY: Nothing to be done for... what? What target does it mention? And are you sure that the target does not already exist? Also, hat version of Make are you using? (`make -v` if you're not sure.)

Comment: GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Btw my pc is 64bit!

Comment: I have updated the makefile. I use include now ( but It looks like this isn't the problem) when I go the directory and do make, i still get the same responce. Check the updated file please. I think the problem is with the objects directory.

Comment: @alienCY: I think the problem is in the subdirectories. I urge you once again to try the simplified version; until you get some version working, the bug could be anywhere.

Comment: Updated it. Now I get a compiling error but otherwise it more or less works. Could you please explain me why it only compiles the first *.o file in the variable if I don't add the line`all: $(OBJ)` ?

Comment: Thanks for your help :D I would upload an answer for this but you helped so I ticked your answer :D I changed in my c++ code the include to `#include "../general/generalParameters.hpp"` and I added `make run` in my bash script that I use to do operations on my project ( It's so cool >.< ).
Thanks again for your help :D